# SharePoint: SPContext.Current returns null for in SharePoint foundation 2010

Tags: sharepoint

I am using the below code to access the web-application from sharepoint.

```
SPWebApplication webApplication = SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication;
```

it works fine with the sharepoint **server 2010(MOSS2010)**. But when I work with SharePoint foundation 2010(WSS4.0)  **SPContext.Current** always returns null. Can anyone tell me what could be the reason for this? and how can i resolve this issue?

Thanks and regards,
Sharmila

Comment: Are you sure `SPContext.Current` is `null`? Where does this code run (WebPart/Console Application/TimerJob)?

Comment: Yes.SPContext.Current returns null. The code runs in webpart

Comment: Is this a sandboxed solution (in the Foundation environment)?

Comment: @Mishal Did you ever find a solution for this, I'm having a similar issue with an assembly I deployed manually to sharepoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the common reasons I've seen where SPContext is found to be null is when you have an incorrectly configured AAM. Its really important that sharepoint understands what URLs are configured for your site because if your URL is not registered it cant tell if the URL is inside the SPContext hence create it.

> The most common change Ive seen is modifying the host headers of the
>   IIS site. This is an enormous no-no, please don't ever do this (use
>   AAM's instead). If you do go ahead and modify these any of your newly
>   added headers will only be partly functional. Inside of SharePoint
>   there is a lot of components which rely directly on the URL and in
>   particular on looking this URL up internally. What you find (for the
>   developers) is that references to SPContext.Current (a core piece of
>   SharePoint goodness) will not work. This causes havoc on random
>   SharePoint pages, web parts and custom features.

Take a look here if you want to know how to setup AAMs (and find out why they are so important) take a look at my blog post on the subject
http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2011/05/sharepoint-alternate-access-mappings.html

Answer (score 0):

When you built your code, did you build it on an SP2010 Server machine, and then deploy the code to a Foundation machine? If you did, I suspect that you'll need to rebuild the code on a Foundation server, referencing the Foundation assemblies, not the Server assemblies.

Comment: `SPContext` object is a core concept found in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll assembly, it is common in both foundation and the office server.

Comment: I have compiled the code separately in Foundation 2010(wss4.0)but SPContext.Current is null. But SPContext.Current is available for sitecollection. but it is null for when the webpart is deployed for web-application.

Comment: Hello, I have found that SPContext.Current is available in the FeatureActivated method in the reciever.However it is null when I try to access the webapplication from anywhere else.

Comment: Any ideas? why SPContext.Current is not available?