# Why does SPContext.Current return a null value?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013

I am new in SharePoint development and I am developing a custom SharePoint Farm Solution. I am currently having an issue with code which runs properly on the production and test environments but gives an error on the development and I don't know why. The source code looks identical in all environments. I was able to locate the error through debugging and I found that it gives an error on the following line:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
```

The code is about sending an email upon the completion of course evaluation function in my application. Here's the code:

```
MailConfiguration config = new MailConfiguration();
MailNotification content = config.GetMailNotification(userId, courseId);
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
string subject = content.Subject;
string msgBody = content.Body;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
{
     bool result = SPUtility.SendEmail(web, appendHtmlTag, htmlEncode, content.To, subject, msgBody);
     message = "Email sent successfully";
});
```

**Could you please explain to me why this is happening?** The SendEmail function is not working now due to this error.

Comment: you need to be authenticated to access the SPContext.Current object.

Comment: Maybe this link is helpful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725255/sharepoint-spcontext-current-returns-null-for-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010

Comment: @Saadi, Thanks for your answers. Kindly note that I have an administrator access to the application and I can access the system and most of the pages/ functionalities are working well except this one. In addition, the link you provided is discussing the alternate mapping access which I don't have in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Check the follows:

1.Check the alternate mapping access(AAMs). If not, configure it.

2.Check if have Site Collection at the root of the SharePoint website.

3.Use the method below to create a fake SPContext in a non-SharePoint context.

```
public static SPContext FakeSPContext(SPWeb web)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
    {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest("", web.Url, "");
        HttpContext.Current = new HttpContext(request, new HttpResponse(TextWriter.Null));
    }

    if (HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["HttpHandlerSPWeb"] = web;
    }

    return SPContext.Current;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. A question: I don't have any (AAMs) in my environment. The url to the application is something like http://ps2013:28312/workapp, so should I configure the AAM by editing the public URL to something else?

Comment: you can configure the AAM with the local IP Address

Comment: Could you please share with me a reference showing how to configure AAM with local IP Address?